# How to access local music files/directory with HTML5 Ubuntu App?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I'm building an Ubuntu app in HTML5, using the Ubuntu SDK. From what I can tell, I should be using `contentHub` to access music files in `/home/Music/`, however I can't make heads or tails of the API. (https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/html5/sdk-15.04/ContentHub.ContentHub/)

How exactly would I go about importing the files, and how would I interact with them after I did so, if I, say, wanted to display a list of all of them?

I assume I'd import it using  `api.importContent( type, peer, transferOptions, onError, onSuccess )` , but I have no idea what an acceptable value for `peer` would be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to some code that I wrote that does exactly what I think you need:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~rick-rickspencer3/+junk/flash2/view/head:/components/AddSoundDialog.qml

This will leave any music files that the user picks in a Music directory in your apps's data directory.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'll take a look, hopefully it will solve my lack-of-understanding/problems :)